# Xamarin Won't Build on Physical Devices

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, csproj

I'm building a Xamarin app, and, so far, I've been able to build without issue on the iPhone Simulator, but I haven't been able to get the app to launch successfully on a physical iPhone device. In the past (about a month ago), the app was working fine on the same device. Here's some background on the specifics:

- I develop my Xamarin code on my Windows machine, which is linked a  remote Mac (hosted by MacStadium, a third-party hosting service).
- My test phone is an iPhone 5c running iOS 10.3.3
- To deploy to my iPhone, I build my app in Release mode in Visual Studio, upload the code to a third-party app installation service, Installr, which hosts the IPA file and assists with the installation of my app on the physical device. I've never had an issue with Installr and have no reason to believe that this is the source of my problem.
- Since the last time the app worked on the physical device, I updated Visual Studio to version 16.3.2 and updated Xamarin. Here's the Xamarin Specs:
  [image: Xamarin Versions]

Generally, what happens, is that I download and install my app on the iPhone without any issue. However, when I click on the app, the splash screen loads for about 5 seconds, a white screen briefly appears as follow, then the app crashes.

[image: White screen that appears before crash]

I've seen several related articles on StackOverflow and other sources on the internet, but none of the proposed solutions see to work for me. For example, I've tried adding `[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]`
 to App.xaml.cs with no luck.

I've also played around with changing the CSProj file settings to compile for various combinations of ARM64 and ARMv7. Changing this didn't help either. I've tried changing the linker behavior to "Don't Link" from "Link Framework SDKs Only", and I get an error message stating that the native code is too large for 32-bit architectures. I would compile for only 64-architectures to get around this error, but I believe that the iPhone 5c uses a 32-bit architecture.

Here's what my iOS Project's CSProj file looks like currently. I've tried checking just about all of those checkboxes with no luck:

[image: IOS CSProj file]

I'm stumped as to what this could be. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. To further complicate things, I haven't been able to get a good log file from the iPhone. Since the Mac is remotely hosted, I can't plug my phone into XCode to pull the logs that way. Does anyone have a reliable solution to get log files another way?

Comment: Is there any debugging output (stack trace or core dump)?

Comment: Hi , does program works when debug on Physical Devices , you can first check this .

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I wasn't able to get the debugger to attach to the physical phone. I think this might be because I don't have physical access to the Mac? Anyway, I updated Visual Studio to 16.3.5 from 16.3.2, and I updated XCode on the Mac to Version 11.1. After this, Visual Studio upgraded something automatically when it connected to the Mac remotely. Not sure what was in these updates exactly, but it seems to be building now on my iPhone!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like upgrading solved the problem. Visual Studio was updated to Visual Studio to 16.3.5 from 16.3.2. XCode on my Mac was updated to Version 11.1. After these updates, Visual Studio performed an update while connecting to the Mac remotely.